# Google play error when trying to update beta

Tags: android, google-play

I'm receiving this error when trying to upload a new apk to my beta channel:

> **Errors**
>
> Resolve these errors before starting the rollout of this release.
>
> *You can't rollout this release because it doesn't allow any existing users to upgrade to the newly added APKs.*

In my alpha channel, witch is updated far more frequently, I can successfully upload the same apk.

How can I solve it?

Comment: Happening with me too

Comment: I've contacted the google play support, they said they would contact the technical team to evaluate my problem and mail me later. Four hours later I was able to use my apk without error, even not receiving they answer. I'm not sure if someone there did something, but it's right as intended right now.

Comment: I was facing the same issue yesterday. But was able to publish the app without any issue today. Whatever the issue was, I think they have solved it.

Answer (score 18):

I was able to get around this error because I had accidentally set my Version Code to a lower number than the Version Code for an APK in production.  Once I increased my version code number to be larger than any previous releases, it worked.

[image]