# You can't rollout this release because it doesn't allow any existing users to upgrade to the newly added APKs in Flutter app

Tags: android, flutter, dart, google-play-console

I am trying to update my app whose previous version is already in publish. I am getting error below:
[image]

I guess my problem is different from answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47214125/google-play-store-release-issue) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46222757/google-play-error-when-trying-to-update-beta)

In previous release i have published apk using flutter command `flutter build apk --split-per-abi`. But now in this release i am trying to update app using `flutter build appbundle`

Here in the below picture when i generated bundle it gives version code to bundle from `pubspec.yaml`

[image]

But here now i see that when i generated apks(**not bundle**) play console generated version codes like **1032**, **2032**, **4032**:

[image]

So i guess problem is there. bundle version code **38** is definitely smaller than apks' **1032**. How can i solve that? Or am i wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Google Play does not generate version codes. The version codes 1032, 2032, 4032, ... have been set by you (I imagine through a Gradle plugin extension that used this version code scheme for the different ABIs).

Because you can never publish an app with a version lower than one already published, you should now use versionCodes greater than previous ones, hence your App Bundle should now have **version 4033 or higher**.

Comment: Thanks for info. I just went with  `flutter build apk --split-per-abi`